# How not to show on a page of chunk of layout?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-blade

I have a common layout to all pages in it, I do include "form search" (search in the header).
But on the page "global search" I would not like to display the search.

How to do it nicely? Check the title or route, the only thing that came to mind

```
Layout -> include (search.form) -> Page
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your best option here is to utilise `Route::is($name)` in your view. This allows you to check if a certain route is being accessed, it does require the use of a named route, however.

#### routes.php

```
Route::get('/search', ['uses' => 'SearchController@search', 'as' => 'global-search']);
```

#### View

```
@if ( ! Route::is('global-search'))

    @include('search.form')

@endif
```